# How to increase FastAPI timeout in Docker to be deployed on AWS EB?

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, gunicorn, fastapi, uvicorn

I am deploying a FastAPI application which is dockerized. I deployed that dockerized file on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. But for some functions, the process is taking more than 60 seconds, and it times out. I need the timeout to be at least 300 seconds. How can I accomplish this?
I tried CMD and ENTRYPOINT in the Dockerfile, but didn't work. I tried using gunicorn config file with timeout settings but didn't work. I also tried modifying dockerrun.aws.json with the code '"timeout":300', didn't work as well. What is the best solution to this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know where the timeout is coming from? What error are you getting when the request times out?

Comment: Gateway 504 Timeout error

Comment: hey Vishvesh, I'm having the same issue. Were you able to fix it?? I don't know what else I can try

Comment: Yeah I solved it by switching to an asynchronous API with Celery and Redis. You have to make frequent requests from the frontend to receive the results though